# How to get data of nested Relation in laravel

Tags: laravel

Let me explain the actual case. I have three tables like:

1. products table
   [image]
2. shop table:

   [image]
3. users table:
   [image]

Here `shop_id` of `product` table is the foreign key of `shop` table. Again `shop_owner_id` of shop table is foreign key of users table. Now I have `product_id` and I want to get `shop_owner_id`. I can do this as follows:

```
STEP 1. get `shop_id` from `product_id`
STEP 2. get `shop_owner_id` from `shop_id`
```

OR I can write a raw sql query to join these there table and get the `shop_owner_id` from `product_id`. But is there any descent way in laravel.

Comment: Do you have the relationships set up in your Eloquent model i.e. `product` -belongsTo-> `shop` and `shop` -belongsTo-> `user` (owner)?

Comment: Thanks a million. I am wonder how much stupid am I !. Just this relationship setup solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can deduct that that

- User has shops and Shop belongs to a user
- Shop has many products and product belongs to a shop

To define relation, It can be performed inside of each Model like this

```
class Shop extends Model {
    public function products() {
        return this->hasMany('App\Models\Product', 'shop_id');
    }

    public function user() {
        return this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product', 'shop_owner_id');
    }
}

class Product extends Model {
    public function shop() {
        return this->belongsTo('App\Models\Shop', 'shop_id');
    }
}


class User extends Model {
    public function shop() {
        return this->hasMany('App\Models\Shop', 'shop_owner_id');
        
        // or if user can have a single shop

        return this->hasOne('App\Models\Shop', 'shop_owner_id');
    }
}
```